# How to make a struct of structs in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

Can a struct contain other structs?

I would like to make a struct that holds an array of four other structs. Is this possible? What would the code look like?

Comment: Since the solution to the question is obvious—just declare what you want—but there are a lot of pitfalls to doing this, maybe a code sample is in order.

Comment: -1. Asking without even trying is very impolite

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can.  For example, this struct `S2` contains an array of four `S1` objects:

```
struct S1 { int a; };

struct S2
{
    S1 the_array[4];
};
```

Comment: The struct keyword for declarations isn't necessary for C++

Comment: @Axel:  This question is tagged `[c]`.  **Correction:**  This question _was_ tagged `[c]`.  I've edited it to C++ify it; thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, why not.

```
struct foo {
    struct {
        int a;
        char *b;
    } bar[4];
} baz;

baz.bar[1].a = 5;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, structs can contain other structs. For example:

```
struct sample {
  int i;
  char c;
};

struct b {
  struct sample first;
  struct sample second;
};
```